# Move view when a specific textfield is selected swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewwilldisappear

I am created a meme generator app to better learn Swift and Xcode. I am learning to move the view when the user interacts with a text field that would be obstructed by the keyboard. I have this functionality working, with one exception. The desired functionality is to have the view slide up when the user is entering text for the bottom textfield, bot the top. The view slides up regardless of the text field the user is interacting with.

[image]

How can I assign this functionality only to the bottom text field? Here is my source code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagePickerView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cameraButton: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var topText: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomText: UITextField!

    let memeTextAttributes:[String:Any] = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.strokeColor.rawValue: UIColor.black,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.white,
        NSAttributedStringKey.font.rawValue: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-CondensedBlack", size: 30)!,
        NSAttributedStringKey.strokeWidth.rawValue: -5.0]

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        subscribeToKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Diable camer a button if camera ource isn't available
        cameraButton.isEnabled = UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
        topText.delegate = self
        bottomText.delegate = self
        topText.textAlignment = .center
        bottomText.textAlignment = .center
        topText.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
        bottomText.defaultTextAttributes = memeTextAttributes
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications()
    }

    // MARK: Delegate Methods

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
            imagePickerView.image = image
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.text = ""
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.topText.resignFirstResponder()
        self.bottomText.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    // MARK: Move the keyboard up when the bottom textfield is tapped

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
        view.frame.origin.y = 0 - getKeyboardHeight(notification)
    }

    func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) -> CGFloat {
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue // of CGRect
        return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
    }

    func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    }

    // MARK: Move view down when keyboard is dismissed

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
        view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }

    // MARK: IBActions

    @IBAction func pickAnImageFromAlbum(_ sender: Any) {
        let pickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        pickerController.delegate = self
        pickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        present(pickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func pickAnImageFromCamera(_ sender: Any) {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.sourceType = .camera
        present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply try this

```
  //make a global textField to keep reference
var currentTappedTextField : UITextField?
//use this method to get tapped textField
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   currentTappedTextField = textField
    return true
}
// now move view only when textfield is bottom
@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification:Notification) {
    if(currentTappedTextField == bottomText){
   view.frame.origin.y = 0 - getKeyboardHeight(notification)
    }
}
```

Comment: If I run the app in iPhone 4s. I am sure topTextField will also hide under keyboard, if the view is not centre aligned to view. Then how you will solve it.

Comment: I use TPKeyboard so i don't worry about these keyboard like thing. But this was the answer of asked question

Comment: Dude I am telling about asked question itself.

Comment: What question is being asked is "How can I assign this functionality only to the bottom text field". please check it

Comment: k dude understood

Answer (score 1):

Add view in scrollview.
Use

```
pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
```

It will automatically handle that. In app delegate write this code :

```
 IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
 IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 30.0
```

If you want for one textfield:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool { 
    if textField == toptextField {
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = false 
    }
    else {
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    } 
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you. How would I achieve this without scroll view? I want to assign the functionality I wrote to the bottom text field only.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a delegate file and only include the functionality in the bottom text field's delegate?

Comment: Hmmm, this didn't work, but it does have me wondering if I can use an if statement within one of these methods to ensure this functionality is only called when the bottomText textfield is pressed. Is that possible? Where would I attempt that?

Comment: I don't think you have to write any code for keyboard event any where. Please do one thing remove all the code for moving the textfield. Then install the pod and write those two lines in appDelegate. This will definitely work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161104/discussion-between-rahul-dasgupta-and-andrew-tuzson).

Answer (score 1):

## Approach without using external framework:

1. Use a bottom constraint from the text field to the parent view.
2. Adjust the constant value based on whether the keyboard is shown or hidden.

## Steps:

1. Create a bottom constraint from your text field to the parent view.
2. Set the constraint's constant to an initial desired value
3. Add store the constraint as a property in the view controller
4. Observe `UIKeyboardDidShow` notification and get the end frame of the keyboard. Use the negative height of the end frame as the bottom constraint's constant.
5. Similarly do the same in `UIKeyboardWillHide` and set the bottom constraint constant to the original constant value

Answer (score 0):

You just need to observe Keyboard Notification in your viewDidLoad :

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide),
                                           name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)   
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
```

And declare selector methods to change your view constraint :

```
@objc
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let keyboardHeight = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue {
        yourViewBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight.cgRectValue.height + constantHeight
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}

@objc
func keyboardWillHide() {
    yourViewBottomConstraint.constant = constantHeight
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Just don't forget to implement UITextFieldDelegate :

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return false
    }
}
```